# What's the best way to replicate a multiregion storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, replication

I've got a customer requirement to replicate a multiregion storage bucket (Mr Bucket A --> Mr Bucket B) so that every new object gets copied. Would Cloud Functions be the way to go here?

Comment: Yes, use Cloud Functions. There are many good reasons to replicate buckets for security, integrity and auditing purposes. You can trigger on the bucket itself or from StackDriver logs. The comment thread on Doug's correct answer is too long so I am posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Storage already has [multiregion replication](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/store-it-analyze-it-back-it-up-cloud-storage-updates-bring-new-replication-options).  But if that's not what you're looking for, a Cloud Functions trigger that copies each new file might be the only efficient mechanism.

Comment: Yeah, but we need it in separate buckets (and separate projects). It's excessive, but that's what they want. I thought cloud function would be best, with a trigger on: object created or time would be the best way to do it.

Comment: There is no trigger for time.  You will want to use finalize and delete to determine when a file changes.  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage

Comment: It looks like object change would be the best trigger.

Comment: What about Cloud Scheduler:

Comment: If you're looking for a conversation about your problem rather than something with a discrete answer, may I recommend you take it to a discussion forum, rather than dragging out comments.  Stack Overflow was not designed for extended comments not related to the original question.

Comment: These comment are related to the original question. Thanks for your well-intentioned police work but you're wrong.

Comment: I don't know how you would use cloud scheduler to copy files anyway.

Comment: You could schedule a pub/sub message and then trigger off the message to do a bucket sync job. This would have the advantage of allowing to sync all your buckets.

Comment: You also need a strategy for figuring out which files need to be copied.